# Using protobuf-net, is it possible to deserialize a message without allocating memory?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a C# application that needs to deserialize many thousands of protobuf messages per second. In the interest of avoiding unnecessary garbage collections, I'm wondering if there is a way to use pre-allocated memory so that each deserialization operation wouldn't need to allocate new memory.

What I envision is that I would allocate a pool of message objects prior to execution, and then instruct the protobuf code to use the next available message from this pool for each deserialization.

Does this functionality exist, or is there some other way to optimize memory use in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you determined that this is in fact as issue? Have you run into this scenario where you're app is either running low on memory or is running slow due to garbage collections?

Comment: No, but that is the only region of code in this high frequency component that is currently required to allocate memory, so it seems worthwhile to me to explore the possibility of eliminating it, especially if there is a straightforward approach to do so.

Comment: Allocation and garbage collection of objects that are short-lived is extremely fast. You probably shouldn't worry about this unless you actually profile your code and find out this is the bottleneck.

Comment: For some people extremely fast is a problem. I have a software that regularly tests a set of files with about 11 billion entries - and should do so as fast as possible. Adding around 500 million entries per day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is! Internally, it already uses a micro-pool to avoid allocating too many working buffers, but if you are putting through enough objects that GC is an issue, you can perhaps use your own allocation scheme, and create a custom object factory; this cannot be specified on the *attributes* currently, but can be applied via the type-model:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof (Foo), true).SetFactory(factory);
```

where `factory` is either:

- the **name** of a `static` method on `Foo` (i.e. `"CreateFoo"`) that returns a `Foo`
- the `MethodInfo` of any `static` method (does not need to be on `Foo`) that returns a `Foo`

in either case, the method can use the same signatures as callbacks - so it can be parameterless, or can accept context information. For example:

```
public static Foo CreateFoo() {
    return GetFromYourOwnMicroPool();
}
```

Note that in this usage, it is expected that the **factory** will reset the object to a vanilla state; protobuf-net will not attempt to do this. Note also that currently protobuf-net doesn't expose it's micro-pool as a reusable component, but you could re-use the source easily enough.

This functionality was specifically added to support a user with very high throughput who wanted to remove even the slightest GC overheads (based on lots of measurements... they sent me pretty graphs and everything ;p)

Additionally: **with the exception of the root object**, protobuf-net supports `struct` values without boxing; so if you have a complex/nested object model, another option *in extreme cases* is to look at `struct`s.

Comment: Can you please clarify how to use structs? Can we do that when generating from a proto file? What about this statement on the github readme? `The code assumes that types will be mutable around the elected members. Accordingly, custom structs are not supported, since they should be immutable.`

Comment: @Aranda that remark may pre-date the support for structs. The generation tool only emits classes at the moment, but structs should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I did get it working by manually editing the generated classes to be structs (for non-root types), but could not eliminate all allocations as both the factory approach and merge approach did not seem to eliminate the allocation of the root types. We're trialing a switch to Flatbuffers for now.

Comment: Does anyone have a working example of the above concept?

Comment: @rolls I can almost certainly help, but this is a very old question; might be worth creating a fresh issue on the GitHub, making it clear what you're trying to do.